# Standard behavior when reloading a web page containing radio buttons

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

I have this html page:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
          <input id="europe" name="continents" type="radio" checked="checked"></input>
          <label for="europe">Europe</label>
          <br>
          <input id="africa" name="continents" type="radio"></input>
          <label for="africa">Africa</label>
          <br>
          <input id="asia" name="continents" type="radio"></input>
          <label for="asia">Asia</label>
          <br>
          <input id="america" name="continents" type="radio"></input>
          <label for="america">Ameria</label>
          <br>
          <input id="others" name="continents" type="radio"></input>
          <label for="others">Others</label>
          <br>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

..which renders as follows:

[image]

As you can see in the snippet, Europe is checked by default  with `checked="checked"`.

In Firerox when you select another continent, say America and press `F5` or `Ctrl-R`, the page is reloaded but the selection is "remembered", meaning America is checked even after reloading the page. You have to hit `Ctrl+F5` for it to reload to a state where Europe is checked as the code says by default.

In Chrome the selection is not "remembered" even when reloading with `F5` or `Ctrl-R`.

In my opinion the Chrome behavior is more logical.

**- What is the standard behavior?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgetfulness is standard behavior. That's a full page refresh. Firefox's can be a handy feature though.

Also, *I think*, that is unless the GET variables in the URL are defined, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/?continents=America